# Refactoring rest request in SPFx Web aprt

Tags: rest, spfx

I have worked in a web part that fetch items from a SP list and then filter or groups these results.
For each filter action I send a new request to SP with Rest and I am using the rest code to get back the filtered items and show them in the web part.
Right now I have two filter actions triggered by onClick events.

Each action looks like this:
To filter by closed agreements:

```
private getEnded(): void {
this.props.provider.getEnded().then((originalitems: IList[]) => {

  this.setState({
    filteredListItems: originalitems,
    filter: true
  });
});
```

}

and to filter by last day passed:

```
 private getPassed(): void {
this.props.provider.getPassed().then((originalitems: IList[]) => {
  this.setState({
    filteredListItems: originalitems,
    filter: true
  });
});
```

}

and in the dataprovider file I have these methods, each one of them make request to SharePoint, the only difference is the filter parameter:

To get closed agreements (called from the method getEnded()):

```
public async getEnded(): Promise<IList[]> {
let today = new Date();
let Agreements: IList[] = [];

const items = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("AgreementDatabase")
  .items.select(this.select)
  .filter(
    `(AgreementEnded eq true) and (AgreementEndDate le '${today.toISOString()}')`
  )
  .expand("SalesManager,TaxCatchAll,FrameworkAgreement")
  .get();

items.forEach(item => {
  Agreements.push({
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id,
    CustomerAgreementNr: item.CustomerAgreementNr,
    AgreementType: item.AgreementType,
    Customer: item.TaxCatchAll[0].Term,
    FrameworkAgreement: item.FrameworkAgreement.Title,
    ContactPerson: item.ContactPerson,
    SalesManager: item.SalesManager.FirstName + " " + item.SalesManager.LastName,
    DeliveryType: item.DeliveryType,
    AgreementStartDate: item.AgreementStartDate,
    AgreementEndDate: item.AgreementEndDate,
    AgreementEnded: item.AgreementEnded,
    LastPriceAdjustment: item.LastPriceAdjustment,
    NextPriceAdjustment: item.NexPriceAdjustment,
  });
});

return new Promise<IList[]>(async resolve => {
  resolve(Agreements);
});
```

}

and to get passed passed agreements (called from the method getPassed()):

```
public async getPassed(): Promise<IList[]> {
let today = new Date();
let Agreements: IList[] = [];


const items = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("AgreementDatabase")
  .items.select(this.select)
  .filter(`LastPriceAdjustment le '${today.toISOString()}'`)
  .expand("SalesManager,TaxCatchAll,FrameworkAgreement")
  .get();

items.forEach(item => {
  Agreements.push({
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id,
    CustomerAgreementNr: item.CustomerAgreementNr,
    AgreementType: item.AgreementType,
    Customer: item.TaxCatchAll[0].Term,
    FrameworkAgreement: item.FrameworkAgreement.Title,
    ContactPerson: item.ContactPerson,
    SalesManager: item.SalesManager.FirstName + " " + item.SalesManager.LastName,
    DeliveryType: item.DeliveryType,
    AgreementStartDate: item.AgreementStartDate,
    AgreementEndDate: item.AgreementEndDate,
    AgreementEnded: item.AgreementEnded,
    LastPriceAdjustment: item.LastPriceAdjustment,
    NextPriceAdjustment: item.NexPriceAdjustment,
  });
});

return new Promise<IList[]>(async resolve => {
  resolve(Agreements);
});
```

}

As you can see the method that request information from SP are almost identical, the only difference is the filter parameter.
I am wondering how can I resuse just one of this rest method tho fetch and filter data from sharepoint?

Best regards
Americo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write one method and pass the filer:

```
private getEnded(): void {
const filter = `(AgreementEnded eq true) and (AgreementEndDate le '${today.toISOString()}')`;
this.props.provider.getAgreements(filter).then((originalitems: IList[]) => {

  this.setState({
    filteredListItems: originalitems,
    filter: true
  });
});



 private getPassed(): void {
const filter = `LastPriceAdjustment le '${today.toISOString()}'`;
    this.props.provider.getAgreements(filter).then((originalitems: IList[]) => {
      this.setState({
        filteredListItems: originalitems,
        filter: true
      });
    });

public async getAgreements(filterAgreements: string): Promise<IList[]> {
let today = new Date();
let Agreements: IList[] = [];

const items = await sp.web.lists
  .getByTitle("AgreementDatabase")
  .items.select(this.select)
  .filter(filterAgreements)
  .expand("SalesManager,TaxCatchAll,FrameworkAgreement")
  .get();

items.forEach(item => {
  Agreements.push({
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id,
    CustomerAgreementNr: item.CustomerAgreementNr,
    AgreementType: item.AgreementType,
    Customer: item.TaxCatchAll[0].Term,
    FrameworkAgreement: item.FrameworkAgreement.Title,
    ContactPerson: item.ContactPerson,
    SalesManager: item.SalesManager.FirstName + " " + item.SalesManager.LastName,
    DeliveryType: item.DeliveryType,
    AgreementStartDate: item.AgreementStartDate,
    AgreementEndDate: item.AgreementEndDate,
    AgreementEnded: item.AgreementEnded,
    LastPriceAdjustment: item.LastPriceAdjustment,
    NextPriceAdjustment: item.NexPriceAdjustment,
  });
});

return new Promise<IList[]>(async resolve => {
  resolve(Agreements);
});
```

Other improvement:

You can use .map() instead of .foreach()

```
Agreements = items.map(item => {
    Title: item.Title,
    Id: item.Id,
    CustomerAgreementNr: item.CustomerAgreementNr,
    AgreementType: item.AgreementType,
    Customer: item.TaxCatchAll[0].Term,
    FrameworkAgreement: item.FrameworkAgreement.Title,
    ContactPerson: item.ContactPerson,
    SalesManager: item.SalesManager.FirstName + " " + item.SalesManager.LastName,
    DeliveryType: item.DeliveryType,
    AgreementStartDate: item.AgreementStartDate,
    AgreementEndDate: item.AgreementEndDate,
    AgreementEnded: item.AgreementEnded,
    LastPriceAdjustment: item.LastPriceAdjustment,
    NextPriceAdjustment: item.NexPriceAdjustment,
});
```